# SQL mass updates on Volusion

Tags: sql, volusion

Right now I am trying to update a field for a lot of products using SQL on Volusion but I can't seem to get it right.

[image]

I am trying to update the Package Type to UPS Package for every product but when I update it this way, it just adds another option on the drop down list titled the exact same thing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKu6N.png

I imagine what I should be doing is changing things around so that instead of updating every product I'm making every product choose UPS Package from the existing menu? If I manually change a product to UPS Package (correctly) then export all product data the field is displayed as just a '2' on the spreadsheet, but I also can't just put a '2' in on the mass update.

Thanks in advance

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4p0a.png): [image]

Answer (score 0):

Its the space before the SET value that is causing this, which you would need in order to keep this on the same line (otherwise this becomes products_joinedSET). This was a correction made to any SQL that can be run in a store that was made back in mid November. So any queries with a SET value will need a line break in order to remove that space between the table name and the SET.

> `UPDATE Products_Joined
>   SET Package_Type = 'UPS Package' WHERE ProductPrice = '0'`

Of course, if you want to change ALL your products to UPS Package and have products that are more than $0.00 then you'll need to remove `WHERE ProductPrice = '0'`